# If $A\subseteq \bigcup_n O_n $, then $A+x \subseteq \bigcup_n (O_n + x)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> As the title mentions, I would like to show that if $(O_n)_n$ is a cover of $A$ then $(O_n+x)_n$ is an cover of $A+x$.

Everywhere I see this mentioned states that it is obvious, and I see how it is. But a formal proof for it I haven't been able to find.

Clearly the converse would also be true by taking $I_n=O_n+x$ and so $I_n+(-x)=O_n$

I've seen some people do $A+x \subseteq (\bigcup_n O_n )+x\subseteq \bigcup_n (O_n+x)$ but this looks like a fundamental abuse of notation since $A+x$ is a **set** and not two seperate components

Thanks!

**EDIT:** $O_n$ is not necessarily open

Comment: Yes, a question involving sets is a question about set theory. Not just elementary set theory, but also advanced set theory. I'm surprised you're not using the [open-problem] tag. I mean, it's a problem involving open sets...

Comment: Haha good one! 
(Although it technically isn't about open sets ;D )

Comment: Is it your question related to general topology or measure theory? Feel free to add one (or both) of those tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just show the inclusion: Let $y$ be in $A + x$. This means by definition that $y = a +x$ for some $A \in A$. The $(O_n)$ cover $A$, so for some $m$, $a \in O_m$, but then $y = a+x \in O_m + x$ as required. So $(O_n + x)_n$ covers $A + x$.

More fancy: $f_x: X \to X$ defined by $f_x(p) = p+x$ is a bijection (in any group) and so preserves set theory operations like unions and intersections, so using that $A + x = \{a+x: a \in A\} = \{f_x(a): a \in A\} = f_x[A]$ :

$$(\cup_n O_n) + x = f_x[\cup_n O_n]  =\cup_n f_x[O_n]  =\cup_n (O_n + x)$$ which justifies what you call an abuse of notation. It's in fact completely valid.

Comment: Ahh I see!! Thank you so much! Missed it!